# openpyxl not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, openpyxl

When I run `pandas.ExcelWriter()`, I get the error,

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

When I run `pip3 install openpyxl` I get

```
Requirement already satisfied
```

I don't know if I haven't installed it properly or if there's something else I'm missing.

I'm trying to use it in a jupyter notebook in visual studio code.

Comment: Do you see openpyxl in the list of installed packages when you run `!pip list` in a jupyter cell? I don't think this is a Visual Studio issue, I'd suggest you've installed openpyxl in one environment and your ipykernel is running in a different one.

Comment: It appears in the list when I type that into the terminal

Comment: but not in the jupyter notebook?

Comment: It doesn't appear. How do I ensure it installs there

Comment: In the top right of your jupyter notebook there will be something that probably says "Python ....".  Click that, it allows you to change the environment your notebook is running in.  That environment needs to be the one you have installed openpyxl in.   I suggest you use virtual environments, it'll make managing and finding the right jupyter kernels easier.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selected the suitable environment in the jupyter notebook.

[image]